# Scrapy with S3 support

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy

I have been struggling for the last couple of hours but seem to be blind here. I am trying to establish a link between `scrapy` and Amazon `S3` but keep getting the error that the bucket does not exist (it does, checked a dozen times).

---

The error message:

```
2016-11-01 22:58:08 [scrapy] ERROR: Error storing csv feed (30 items) in: s3://onvista.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/feeds/vista/2016-11-01T21-57-21.csv
```

in combination with

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

---

My `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'onvista.pipelines.OnvistaPipeline': 300,
    #'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 600
}

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
FEED_URI = 's3://onvista.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/feeds/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv'

FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

---

Has anyone a working setting for me to have a glimpse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of referring to an Amazon S3 bucket via its **Hosed Website URL**, refer to it by name.

The [scrapy Feed Exports](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) documentation gives an example of:

```
s3://mybucket/scraping/feeds/%(name)s/%(time)s.json
```

In your case, that would make it:

```
s3://onvista/feeds/%(name)s/%(time)s.json
```

Comment: I'll try this but how does `scrapy` distinguish between the different regions - or is a bucket name always unique worldwide?

Comment: Amazon S3 bucket names are globally unique. Normally it is best to connect to the region where the bucket resides, but they might have some code that handles this.

Comment: Thank you for your effort - I must add that this seems to work only if your bucket is **not** situated in Frankurt, Germany. I dunno why but using a bucket in the US did the trick.

Comment: The Frankfurt region requires authentication to be the newer [AWS Signature version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html), so it's possible that the Scrapy code only uses an older authentication method.